# What causes images to flicker when scrolling?

Tags: image, web, screen

I have no idea what causes this, so I'll refine `tags` as some answers/comments start to guide me in the right direction.

Sometimes, images with monochrome stripey parts (whether the whole image is colour or not), exhibit a strange flashy effect as I scroll past them.

This is where I most recently saw it, [in an article on Dezeen](http://www.dezeen.com/2014/03/17/office-design-google-clive-wilkinson-interview/):
[image]

As I scroll past that image (with Chrome on OS X 10.9) the wall on the right goes darker and brighter, according to my rate of scroll.

If I get *just the right* scroll speed, it doesn't flicker - but it is in the 'dark mode', like someone in the scene has turned the lights off. If I speed up or slow down, it begins to flicker again - so I'm pretty sure it's not an optical elusion!

I saw it before with a couple of `.gif`s, I thought maybe it was a strange property of them. But the image above a is a `.jpg`.

What causes this effect?

Comment: Have you tried playing with your screen refresh rate? (eg. 60/75 Hz) Have you tried using other computers/screens?

Comment: @xav That's a good thought - I don't think it's possible on built-in macbook display though, and I don't have anything else here unfortunately. I know I've seen it before on my desktop @ 75Hz.

Comment: I just tried to scroll this image down at 60 Hz then 75 Hz: it seems to flicker more at 60 Hz... Maybe it's also due to display lag: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_lag  You may have more precise answers here: http://physics.stackexchange.com

Comment: @xav - excellent, sounds like you've solved that mystery for me! (Now I should get back to work..) I suppose the refresh rate makes sense now I think about it, didn't know about display lag. Thanks!

Comment: The effect is [Moiré](http://bit.ly/1mph3s2) see advanced user notes which may help better explain. See also [moire effect](http://bit.ly/1gZ4lMX)

Comment: @Skip R - but that's visible when the image is still, how does that translate to a flicker when scrolling?

Comment: @ollieford I am not an expert but you are creating motion from scrolling, so the effect is just like the moiré you see when someone wear stripes in a TV broadcast. Higher resolution screen would have less impact I guess and different refresh rates would be factors that change moiré effect. I think it is moiré effect (I think that's what it is called), that is, you are seeing the "refresh rate" which is more noticeable with this sort of pattern. You can also see it if you make a small window and scroll image horizontally (rather than vertical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to scroll this image down with my screen refresh rate at 60 Hz then 75 Hz: it seems to flicker more at 60 Hz... Maybe it's also due to [display lag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_lag).

PS: You may have more precise answers here: http://physics.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a [Moiré optical illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern) due to the wall's thin, closely put together horizontal lines, not anything to do with scrolling or display at all.

@SkipR's reply should have been the accepted answer.